# Counting Elements of a Sequence in an Interval

Tags: analysis, elementary-number-theory, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Fix $ a >0 $.
Define $ f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R} $ by
\begin{equation}
   f(n)= n + \lfloor k n -  \tfrac{k }{2} +\tfrac12 \rfloor.
  \end{equation}
Given an interval $ [a,b] \subset \mathbb{R} $, I want to figure out how many elements of the image of $ f $ lie in this interval.

My approach was to start with
\begin{equation}\label{key}
n +  k n -  \tfrac{k }{2} - \tfrac12  \le f(n) \le n +  k n -  \tfrac{k }{2} +\tfrac12, 
\end{equation}

and then invert the inequalities. However, I got stuck.